# Generalization of the Dirichlet Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $(p_1, ..., p_n) \sim \operatorname{Dir}(\boldsymbol{\alpha})$, where $\operatorname{Dir}(\boldsymbol{\alpha})$ is the [Dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) with parameter vector $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$. The support of this distribution is such that $0 \leq p_i \leq 1, \,\forall i \in \lbrace 1,...,n \rbrace$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i = 1$.

Now consider the following generalization: I want the support to be such that $a_i \leq p_i \leq b_i, \,\forall i \in \lbrace 1,...,n \rbrace$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i = c$, where $\boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{b}$ and $c$ are given parameters.

Firstly I've considered generating $\boldsymbol{p}\sim \operatorname{Dir}(\boldsymbol{\alpha})$ and defining $p^{\prime}_i = a_i + (b_i-a_i)p_i$. But the problem is that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} p^{\prime}_i$ is not constrained to a fixed value...

So the question is: does the Dirichlet distribution have a canonical generalization to the support I've defined above? Is it a named distribution? Are there some references to this or related generalizations?

Answer (score 1):

The support of the Dirichlet distribution lies in a plane where

$$\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{1} = 1$$

where $\mathbf{1}$ is the vector of all ones. Which we can write in canonical form as:

$$\left(\mathbf{p}-\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}\right)\cdot\mathbf{1} = 0$$

If I have understood correctly, you are asking for a distribution which is like the Dirichlet but lies in the plane

$$(P1)\;\;\;\;\;\left(\mathbf{p}-\frac{c}{n}\mathbf{1}\right)\cdot\mathbf{1} = 0$$

then you found a conflict when you used the plane

$$(P2)\;\;\;\;\;\left(\left(\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{a}\right) - \frac{1}{n}\left(\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{a}\right)\right)\cdot\left[\left(b_i-a_i\right)^{-1}\right] = 0$$

because, in general, they are not the same, and perhaps they do not even intercept in the region you want. So, first of all, there is no reason why P1 and P2 should coincide. I think the way forward is to discard P2.

Assuming $c>0$, we can find some constraints on $a_i$ and $b_i$. But it's not nice. The conditions $a_i \leq p_i \leq b_i$ define a hypercuboid, and the intersection with P1 is your support. This shape can be calculated using some basic geometry, but bear in mind that will produce a result that will increase combinatorially with dimension (potentially, if numerical, and definitely if algabraic).

However, this does not guarantee that your support will cover the range specified for each variable. "Intuitively", it must cut through the thickest part of the hypercuboid to do this (which is not necessarily possible).

As for what probabilities to map onto this, I don't know. You could just take a region of the Dirichlet distribution and renormalise. It really depends why you are doing it.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I don't understand your equation (P2). The hypercuboid constraints cannot be represented with a plane equation. As for what I'm doing with this, I'm tring to set up a prior distribution on this support, which is the parametric space for my model. I need the hyperparameters $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ (or something similar) to make the prior "non-informative" as $\boldsymbol{\alpha} \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft Your transformation describes a plane (or rather, a simplex lying in one). Though I made a mistake in the equation. My bad.